# htmlagilitypack - parse a tag

Tags: c#, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Im trying to grab the LOC=URL from the following href

```
http://url.comclickThrough?SRC=&amp;target=SP&amp;PN=1&amp;FP=listings&amp;T=Las+Vegas&amp;S=NV&amp;C=lawyer&amp;PGID=yp604.8084.1349604581940.36701144470449&amp;ALG=113&amp;TS=nbt&amp;OF=1&amp;ACTION=log,red&amp;CID=520623&amp;LID=2325743402&amp;TR=77&amp;bidType=FLCLIK&amp;relativePosition=3&amp;position=33&amp;PGSN=R1&amp;RS=49.157852&amp;CID=520623&amp;FL=url&amp;TL=off&amp;LOC=http://www.nvtalaw.com
```

How can i get the last URL in the href?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know about html-agility-pack but it can be parsed by using [System.Web.HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) class

```
System.Uri u = new System.Uri(url);
string LOC = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(u.Query).Get("LOC");
```